# Magento 2.3.3 Store Switcher error

Tags: magento2.3.3, store-switcher

I have created multiple stores with multiple domains but when I select a store from frontend than giving below error.

I have attached the screenshot of the error.

[image]

**Store Cookies does not set on multiple domains**

I have debugged and checked the code and print($fromStoreCode) but give blank. 
**Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction.php**

```
$fromStoreCode = $this->_request->getParam(
            '___from_store',
            $this->storeCookieManager->getStoreCodeFromCookie()
        );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($fromStoreCode);
```

**The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check my attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

ìs the store activated in the backend?

if yes, try this query in the database:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: I have updated my question please check once more time. I have also checked your answer but does not work for me.